# SUM of elapsed time gathered from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to show my team's productivity vs non-productivity percentages based of what type of work they perform throughout the day. I can successfully achieve the format i am looking for with the below code but if an associate is productive in 2 separate departments in 1 day the sub-query fails because it returns multiple rows.

This is what im working with now

```
DECLARE 
    @Offset     INT         ,
    @Start      DATETIME    ,
    @Loc        INT         ,
    @NON        time(0)     ,
    @PROD       time(0)     ,
    @TOTAL      TIME(0)     
    SET @Offset    = 4
    SET @Start     = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -@Offset)

--SUM OF ALL DEPT CATEGORIES WORKED FOR SELECTED DATE RANGE 
select Codes = (DeptCode + ' ' + Opcode)
     , TimeSum = right(convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)) / 3600 )),3) + ':' + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)) / 60) % 60 ),2) 
     , Units = sum(units)
FROM TimeLogNEW 
where EventDate = @Start and Location = 10 and ID = 2372013 
group by EventDate, id, DeptCode, OpCode

--SUM OF NON PRODUCTIVE HOURS WORKED (HAVING A UNITS SUM OF '0' IS CONSIDERED NON PRODUCTIVE) --NOT INCLUDING 'LL' (WHICH IS A LUNCH PERIOD)
set @NON = 
(select NonProd = right(convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,'0:00:00',TimeSum)) / 3600 )),3) + ':' + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(sum(datediff(second,'0:00:00',TimeSum)) / 60) % 60 ),2) 
from (select 
            TimeSum = right(convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,m.StartTime,m.FinishTime)) / 3600 )),3) + ':' + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(sum(datediff(second,m.StartTime,m.FinishTime)) / 60) % 60 ),2) 
           ,Units = sum(m.units)
FROM TimeLogNEW m
where m.EventDate = @Start  and opCode Not in ('ll') and m.Location = 10 and m.ID = 2372013 
group by m.EventDate, m.id, m.DeptCode, m.OpCode
)t Group By Units Having Units = 0)
select @NON as 'NON-PROD_Hours'

--SUM OF PRODUCTIVE HOURS WORKED (HAVING A UNITS SUM OF MORE THAN '0' IS CONSIDERED PRODUCTIVE) --NOT INCLUDING 'LL' (WHICH IS A LUNCH PERIOD)
set @PROD = 
(select TotalProd = right(convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,'0:00:00',TimeSum)) / 3600 )),3) + ':' + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(sum(datediff(second,'0:00:00',TimeSum)) / 60) % 60 ),2)
from (select 
            TimeSum = right(convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,m.StartTime,m.FinishTime)) / 3600 )),3) + ':' + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(sum(datediff(second,m.StartTime,m.FinishTime)) / 60) % 60 ),2) 
           ,Units = sum(m.units)
FROM TimeLogNEW m
where m.EventDate = @Start  and opCode Not in ('ll') and m.Location = 10 and m.ID = 2372013 
group by m.EventDate, m.id, m.DeptCode, m.OpCode
)t Group By Units Having Units >0 )
select @PROD as 'PROD_Hours'

--SUM OF ALL HOURS WORKED --NOT INCLUDING 'LL' (WHICH IS A LUNCH PERIOD) 
set @TOTAL = 
(select 
TotalTime_NoLunch = right(convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)) / 3600 )),3) + ':' + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)) / 60) % 60 ),2) 
FROM TimeLogNEW
where EventDate = @Start  and ID = 2372013 and OpCode not in ('ll'))
select @TOTAL as 'SUM_Hours'

--PERCENTAGE OF PRODUCTIVITY 
select
[Prod%] =convert(varchar(30),(100 *datediff(minute,'0:00:00',@PROD)/datediff(minute,'0:00:00',@TOTAL) )) +'%'

--PERCENTAGE OF NON-PRODUCTIVITY
select
[NON Prod%] =convert(varchar(30),(100 *datediff(minute,'0:00:00',@NON)/datediff(minute,'0:00:00',@TOTAL) )) +'%'
```

Result shown. For 7-2-18

[image]

If more than 1 of the dept categories `codes` has greater than 0 `Units` the sub-query fails. I have been trying to re-arrange the query to allow the grouping of sums equaling 0 and sums having greater than 0, but am stumped here. I am not getting correct results when ungrouping the `Units` column in the sub.

Here is what the raw data looks like with more than 1 productive operation. 7-3-18
[image]

Comment: remove `group by m.EventDate, m.id, m.DeptCode, m.OpCode`.  That is what is making multiple rows happen if they are in multiple departments and since you only want the total the groups are unnecessary

Comment: @indiri Here is the result, i added a pic above, by removing the groups. I had tried this and it does not return correct data. This is showing `Prod %` as 100%. Incorrect,

Comment: Replace "Group By Units Having" by "WHERE". 

Also, since the WHERE clauses restrict the records to only one EventDate and one ID, you can remove the groupings on these columns. I further suggest not to convert back and forth. Just add and save the minutes, convert to varchar only when needed. Try something like CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(Minute, @TotalMinutes, 0), 108).

Comment: @WolfgangK Thanks, but have tried this approach as well, and am not getting what I am looking for. I am adding a screenshot of what the raw data looks like I am querying from. This may help with finding a solution to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you group by DeptCode and OpCode but do not sum these results over the groups. Try this:

```
DECLARE
    @Offset     INT       ,
    @Start      DATETIME  ,
    @Loc        INT = 10  ,
    @NON        INT       ,
    @PROD       INT       ,
    @TOTAL      INT
    SET @Offset    = 4;
    SET @Start     = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -@Offset);

--SUM OF ALL DEPT CATEGORIES WORKED FOR SELECTED DATE RANGE 
WITH 
  TimeLog (EventDate, [Location], ID, DeptCode, OpCode, Units, Seconds) AS (
    SELECT EventDate, [Location], ID, DeptCode, OpCode, SUM(Units)
      , SUM(DATEDIFF(second, StartTime, FinishTime))
    FROM TimeLogNEW
    GROUP BY EventDate, [Location], ID, DeptCode, OpCode
  )
SELECT
    Codes = (DeptCode + ' ' + Opcode)
  , TimeSum = CAST(DATEADD(second, Seconds, 0) AS time(0))
  , Units
FROM TimeLog
WHERE EventDate = @Start AND [Location] = @Loc AND ID = 2372013;

WITH
  TimeLog (EventDate, [Location], ID, DeptCode, OpCode, Units, Seconds) AS (
    SELECT EventDate, [Location], ID, DeptCode, OpCode, SUM(Units)
      , SUM(DATEDIFF(second, StartTime, FinishTime))
    FROM TimeLogNEW
    GROUP BY EventDate, [Location], ID, DeptCode, OpCode
  ),
  TimeSplit (EventDate, Loc, ID, DC, OC, Units, Seconds, NON_PROD, PROD) AS (
    SELECT EventDate, [Location], ID, DeptCode, OpCode, Units, Seconds
      , CASE WHEN Units = 0 THEN Seconds ELSE 0 END
      , CASE WHEN Units > 0 THEN Seconds ELSE 0 END
    FROM TimeLog
  )
SELECT @NON = SUM(NON_PROD), @PROD = SUM(PROD), @TOTAL = SUM(Seconds)
FROM TimeSplit
WHERE EventDate = @Start AND Loc = @Loc AND ID = 2372013 AND OC NOT IN ('LL');

-- RESULTS
SELECT
  CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @NON/3600) + RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(8), DATEADD(second, @NON, 0), 108), 6) AS 'NON-PROD_Hours',
  CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @PROD/3600) + RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(8), DATEADD(second, @PROD, 0), 108), 6) AS 'PROD_Hours',
  CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @TOTAL/3600) + RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(8), DATEADD(second, @TOTAL, 0), 108), 6) AS 'SUM_Hours',
  CAST(100.0 * @PROD / @TOTAL AS varchar(30)) +'%' AS 'Prod%',
  CAST(100.0 * @NON / @TOTAL AS varchar(30)) +'%' AS 'NON Prod%';
```

Comment: This is great, Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @WolfgangK

Comment: What will happen to the 'NON-PROD_Hours', 'PROD_Hours', and 'SUM_Hours' if the sum is greater than  24 hours? I think that is why i was calculating time sum in a different fashion in my original query.

Comment: @DRUIDRUID When the sums are >= 24 Hours (86400 seconds), the casting from seconds to time will indeed fail (in the last SELECT statement). You can instead cast to datetime and use your special type of formatting. Everything else, also the percentage calculation, will work.

Comment: @DRUIDRUID For example:

`CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @TOTAL/3600) + RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(8), DATEADD(second, @TOTAL, 0), 108), 6)`

Comment: @DRUIDRUID , I adjusted my answer to show you how to address the time overflow issue.